# Android: How to start an activity from a non-activity class using a single instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, task, flags

I have a Java class (not activity) and I want to start a new activity from it. I am getting the context of the app on its initialisation and then I m using it to start a new activity as shown below. Although, the code ONLY works if I add the following piece of code `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`
which is not what I want as I only want to have a single instance of each activity.
How can I do the same but instead of creating a new activity getting the one already created? 
My code is:

```
public class Foo {
  ...
  protected Foo(Context context) {
    applicationContext = context;
  }

  private void onButtonClick(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(applicationContext, Bar.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); //doesnt work without that line
    applicationContext.startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you go into more detail about "it doesnt work without that line". Do you get an exception? What does it say?

Comment: IFAIK, you can't do that. If you use an application context, the only way to start an activity is using NEW_TASK because the application context doesn't guarantee you are in activity scope (you could be in a service with your app closed, so only way to start an activity would be to start your application)

Comment: @MichaelSchmidt `Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?` That is what I get without it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that case you need to use Activity context to start new Activity. You should modify you class like below

```
public class Foo {
  ...
  protected Foo(Activity activityContext) {
    this.activityContext= activityContext;
  }

  private void onButtonClick(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(activityContext, Bar.class);
    activityContext.startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

---

But here you code is not clearing the idea, where you are using this class. Because you made this method as private.

Comment: that works! Thank you. I ll have to make sure it has the expected behaviour but it looks closer to what I wanted from everything else I have tried!

Comment: Most welcome. Sure, do that and feel free to update answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```

Use this, it can help

Comment: what is the difference between doing that:
`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`
and that:
`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK`

Comment: because android Docs says "If set, the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack." for the SINGLE_TOP. Which sounds wrong to me